# Chart.js: Cannot read property 'transition' of null

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm trying to plot multiple graphs, one over other for comparison purposes, the approach I'm using here is I've declared a global array called Datasets and am pushing new datasets via button click event. The first dataset loads quite well and as soon as I stack up the second dataset, the code crashes after a while, NOT IMMEDIATELY, with the message,

```
Cannot read property 'transition' of null
```

Here's a snippet of the code

```js
let Datasets = [] 

   // this is inside the click handler
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/getdata/3571/3751',
      success: data => {
        const {days, infected} = data

        Datasets.push({
            label: 'Bangladesh',
            data: infected,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        })

        //function to load graph, works pretty fine
        loadGraph(Datasets, days)
      }
    })
```

Anyone with any idea how this could be solved? Thanks